# How do I make a table adjust to the size of it's background image?

Tags: html, html-table

I need to put text on top of an image, it's exactly like the profile picture in Facebook where you see the photo and it says change picture on the top right on top of the image.

I created a table and put the text on the top right but the problem is that not all images have the same height and the table cuts some before they end. I don't know how to make the table not to cut my image in half and instead be as long as it's required by the image.

E.G: This code only gets me one line of my image:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="300px" valign="top" style="background-image: url(http://www.chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/lujan.jpg);">Your text here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?  By default, tables (and other block-level elements) will expand to accommodate their content.  So you probably have some styles overriding it.  Also, are you using an **img** tag, or a background image?

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to create it this way:
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>

<td valign="top" style="background-image: url(http://www.chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/lujan.jpg);">Your text here</td>

</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Div` Put the `img` on it and create an other div inside that and position it `top:0; right:0` and put what ever you want to have it on top right corner of the image ! and pulse it will resize automatically.   Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/g6gJG/6/) i have made.

Comment: I tried your code but I don't get the text above the image, I just get the text and then the image below it. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the example now it should be fine http://jsfiddle.net/g6gJG/7/ - I had used `//` for comment in CSS :D